# How can we apply a non-vararg function over a va_list?

Tags: c, unit-testing, tuples, quickcheck

### Backstory

I'm porting the [QuickCheck](https://github.com/mcandre/node-quickcheck#readme) unit test framework to C (see the working code at [GitHub](https://github.com/mcandre/qc)). The syntax will be:

```
for_all(property, gen1, gen2, gen3 ...);
```

Where `property` is a function to test, for example `bool is_odd(int)`. `gen1`, `gen2`, etc. are functions that generate input values for `property`. Some generate integers, some generate chars, some generate strings, and so on.

`for_all` will accept a function with arbitrary inputs (any number of arguments, any types of arguments). `for_all` will run the generators, creating test values to pass to the property function. For example, the property `is_odd` is a function with type `bool f(int)`. `for_all` will use the generates to create 100 test cases. If the property returns false for any of them, `for_all` will print the offending test case values. Otherwise, `for_all` will print `"SUCCESS"`.

Thus `for_all` should use a `va_list` to access the generators. Once we call the generator functions, how do we pass them to the property function?

### Example

If `is_odd` has the type `bool f(int)`, how would we implement a function `apply()` that has this syntax:

```
apply(is_odd, generated_values);
```

### Secondary Issue

See [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523154/how-can-i-print-arbitrary-values-in-c).

How can we intelligently print the arbitrary values of a failing test case? A test case may be a single integer, or two characters, or a string, or some combination of the above? We won't know ahead of time whether to use:

- `printf("%d %d %d\n", some_int, some_int, some_int);`
- `printf("%c\n" a_character);`
- `printf("%s%s\n", a_string, a_struct_requiring_its_own_printf_function);`

Comment: I don't think I follow - are you supposed to `a)` call each generator once and receive a whole collection of generated values right away or `b)` call each generator function in a loop to obtain subsequent values to test?

Comment: Ok, I've read the source code, so I understand it's actually `c)` each generator supplies subsequent values for a particular function argument.

Comment: First: Run the given generators to create a test case. Example: `testme(int, char, char)` needs a random integer and two random characters. Once we figure out how to do this, we will have `for_all` run not just one but 100 test cases in a big loop.

Comment: For your secondary issue, you'll need to produce the args and have them laid out either in a special logging function, which you also pass, or by starting a `va_list` and then passing the *started* list into a printing or handling function of some sort (you can use the `va_list` type as a parameter to a function, allowing you to wrap and otherwise muck about with vararg functions).

Comment: @peachykeen Yeah, I figure I'll have to change the API to `for_all(property, gen1, print1, gen2, print2, ...);` to handle arbitrarily complex data types (think RedBlack trees).

Answer (score 3):

The C language is a statically-typed language. It does not have the powers of runtime reflection that other languages do. It also does not provide ways to build arbitrary function calls from runtime-provided types. You need to have some way of knowing what the function signature of `is_odd` is and how many parameter it accepts and what the types of those parameters is. It doesn't even know when it has reached the end of the ... argument list; you need an explicit terminator.

```
enum function_signature {
    returns_bool_accepts_int,
    returns_bool_accepts_float,
    returns_bool_accepts_int_int,
};

typedef bool (*function_returning_bool_accepting_int)(int);
typedef int (*function_generates_int)();

void for_all(function_signature signature, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, signature);
    switch (function_signature)
    {
    case returns_bool_accepts_int:
        {
            function_returning_bool_accepting_int fn = va_arg(ap, function_returning_bool_accepting_int);
            function_generates_int generator;
            do {
                generator = va_arg(ap, function_generates_int);
                if (generator) fn(generator());
            } while (generator);
        }
        break;
    ... etc ...
    }
}
```

Your problem is that QuickCheck was designed to take advantage of JavaScripts high dynamic programmability, something missing from C.

**Update** If you allow arbitrary function signatures, then you need a way to make it static again, say, by making the caller provide the appropriate adapters.

```
typedef void (*function_pointer)();
typedef bool (*function_applicator)(function_pointer, function_pointer);

void for_all(function_applicator apply, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, apply);
    function_pointer target = va_arg(ap, function_pointer);
    function_pointer generator;
    do {
        generator = va_arg(ap, function_pointer);
        if (generator) apply(target, generator);
    } while (generator);
}

// sample caller
typedef bool (*function_returning_bool_accepting_int)(int);
typedef int (*function_returning_int)();
bool apply_one_int(function_pointer target_, function_pointer generator_)
{
    function_returning_bool_accepting_int target = (function_returning_bool_accepting_int)target_;
    function_returning_int generator = (function_returning_int)generator_;
    return target(generator());
}

for_all(apply_one_int, is_odd, generated_values1, generated_values2, (function_pointer)0);



}
```

Comment: Aye, C cannot dynamically determine a function's type signature. That's why explicit generator functions must be supplied. And we can't hardcode that `enum` since the user may want to test a function over custom types (structs, unions, etc.).

Comment: Then you have to push the typing into the caller. See update. (Filling in the gaps I leave as an exercise. I can't do *everything* for you...)

Comment: Heh, no, I wouldn't expect you to. :) In your code, it looks like is_odd is being called on generated_values1 and generated_values2 separately. Remember, each generator represents a piece of the property's input. `is_odd(int)` has arity 1, so it should have a single generator (`gen_int`). `is_equal_to(int a, int b)` has arity 2, so it would have two generators (`gen_int, gen_int`).

Comment: You are welcome to expand the design to support functions with arity greater than 1.

Comment: The design requires creating helper functions for every possible function signature. I'll leave enumeration of the infinite combinations as an exercise for someone else.

Comment: It would be the caller's responsibility to provide the adaptor.